# How can I sum number of a list

Tags: python, list, function

I'm searching how I can create a list of 6 numbers.
And I have a number that I research like 30 who is the result of addition with number of my list

Here a simple example:

```
list=[]
list.append[1,5,5,10,8,2]

and the number that I want in rapport with the list is for example 30
```

So the solution would be 5+5+10+8+2=30

And it returns me the differents steps to have 30

Of course you have a constraint . It is that you can't use the same number 2 times but you can stock a result to use it later.

For the moment I have just a function who returns me the different addition of list but I can't add my result with the next number ..

So my question is ,  how I can create a function who try all posibility of addition with the number of my list  to got, for example here 30,

I would like for example, with my example of my list above:

```
1+5=6 # 30 so I continue, 6+5#11 so I continue ...  And at the end I need find the right way to find 30
```

So here a solution would be :

```
5+5=10
10+10=20
20+8=28
28+2=30   and 30 is my research number so we stop the function and we print the steps to have the good solution.
```

Thanks !

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: i change my post to explains clearlier my question

Comment: are you asking: how do I get all possible combinations of numbers from my list and sum each one up?

Comment: Yes all combinaison of my list who are possible but I want a particular constraint. I edit my post to show you more

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear I'm afraid. I don't understand what you're asking. Perhaps someone else can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a classic problem (I don't remember the name), I wrote a simple back-track based solution for you. There should be better (performance wise) solutions to it.

Instead of printing you can put the answer in a global list or return it with a bit of work.

```
def sub(all_numbers: list, current_index: int, goal: int) -> bool:
    """
    Tries to construct goal using all_numbers[current_index:] if the goal can be reached it will print picked numbers
    and return True
    """
    if current_index >= len(all_numbers):
        return goal == 0
    if goal < 0:
        return False
    current = all_numbers[current_index]
    pick_current_result = sub(all_numbers, current_index + 1, goal - current)
    if pick_current_result:
        print(current)
        return True
    dont_pick_current_result = sub(all_numbers, current_index + 1, goal)
    return dont_pick_current_result


def solve(all_numbers: list, goal: int):
    sub(all_numbers, 0, goal)


solve([1, 5, 5, 10, 8, 2], 30)
```

Comment: @raph Goal is the number you try to find sum of. Here it's 30 at the beginning. In next step we assume to take 1 and search the rest of list (`[5, 5, 10, 8, 2]`) for 29.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach with a recursive generator function:

```
def sumto(n, lst):
    if not n and not lst:  # base case 1: empty list = 0
        yield []
        return
    if n < 0 or not lst:  # base case 2: unsolvable
        return
    head, *tail = lst
    for sol in sumto(n-head, tail):  # recursion 1: use first element
        yield [head] + sol
    yield from sumto(n, tail)  # recursion 2: don't use first element

>>> list(sumto(30, [1,5,5,10,8,2]))
[[5, 5, 10, 8, 2]]
>>> list(sumto(28, [1,5,5,10,8,2]))
[[5, 5, 10, 8]]
>>> list(sumto(42, [1,5,5,10,8,2]))
[]
>>> list(sumto(10, [1,5,5,10,8,2]))
[[5, 5], [10], [8, 2]]
```

Comment: What means  *tail ?

Comment: `tail == lst[1:]`. The notation `a, *b = c` unpacks the iterable `c`, assigns its first element to `a` and packs its rest into list `b`.

Comment: so you take for example first element and you calcul first element with all the other elements of the list ?

Comment: @raph You can, best all in one comment. I can add explanations to the post.

Comment: Did you see my questions ?